# Confusion about using override with constructors

Tags: c++

Since I have overridden the function returnANumber in the derived class, the constructor shall return "overridden" instead of executing the branch in the parent class. But the result is different with what I expect :\

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class NewClass {
public:
    NewClass(){
        returnANumber();
    }
    virtual void returnANumber(){
        cout << "random number blah blah blah";
    }
};

class DeriveClass : public NewClass {
public:
    void returnANumber() override {
        cout << "overridden";
        }
        };

        int main(){
            NewClass NewClass;
            DeriveClass DeriveClassInst;
            DeriveClassInst.returnANumber();
        }
```

Result: "random" "random" "overridden"
The member function seems to be overridden at last, but it didn't work with the constructor.
Expected output: "random" "overridden" "overridden"

Comment: You probably want to post the rest (a small main indicating with calls where the output confuses you). Show the expected and actual output.

Comment: @StoryTeller answer there is terrible in my opinion, it may be worth letting people answer here with a proper answer to what's happening.

Comment: @kabanus But that's not possible, since undefined behaviour cannot be explained in a general case. Each compiler can and will do whatever it wants, based on the resulting logic tree from the implmentation.

Comment: The reason is that C++ objects are constructed from the inside out. Base-classes are constructed before derived classes. So, before a Derived class is made, a base class must be made. When Base's constructor is called, it's not in derived yet and so the virtual function table still has the entry for base's copy of function().

Comment: @kabanus - There is a more detailed, better answer to the same question. It just wasn't accepted.

Comment: @StoryTeller I stand corrected. OP scroll down a bit there.

Comment: @MioBambino - There's no undefined behavior here. Dynamic function dispatch isn't preformed inside the constructor.

Comment: Thx guys, I know what to do now